# Searchbar in built-in viewer in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I am using TeXmaker 5.0.3 to typeset my thesis and the only problem I have is a non-functioning searchbar within the built-in PDF viewer. There is no problem with searching in external viewers such as 'Acrobat Reader' or 'SumatraPDF'. Does anyone have some idea how to make it working?

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in my `TeXmaker 5.0.3`. My searchbar works well. What about using the find tool (shortcut `ctrl+F`) in the TeX-code and then jumping to the PDF (shortcut `ctrl+space` or right mouse click and `Jump to pdf`)?

Comment: @Ñako The searching in editor works as well as the "jumping" from editor to PDF viewer.

Comment: @KJO It doesn't work for text either. I was using magnifier icon to trigger search with no effect.

Comment: @Jindrich, then the above method it could be a halfway solution. Nevertheless, a computer specialist would recommend reinstalling `TeXmaker`... If you have installed the program, what about trying the portable version or vice versa? Or may be you can contact the creator